# Express js produces 404 for .js file that clearly exists

Tags: node.js, express, http-status-code-404, pug

I am making a simple node/express app using the automatically generated layout from express-generator:

```
.
├── app.js
├── bin
│   └── www
├── package.json
├── public
│   ├── images
│   ├── javascripts
│   └── stylesheets
│       └── style.css
├── routes
│   ├── index.js
│   └── users.js
└── views
    ├── error.jade
    ├── index.jade
    └── layout.jade
```

In the '/public/javascripts' directory there is a 'gauge-main.js' file.

This file is referenced in my 'index.jade' file, located in the '/views' directory:

```
extends layout

block head
        head
                meta(charset='utf-8')
                title Index
                link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/gauge-index.css', type='text/css', media='screen', charset='utf-8')
block body
        body
                script(src='/public/javascripts/gauge-main.js', type='text/javascript', charset='utf-8')
```

When the application is run some '*.css' files are linked correctly, but the 'gauge-main.js' produces a 404 error:

```
> ase@0.0.0 start /srv/node/ase
> node ./bin/www

GET / 200 231.694 ms - 424
GET /stylesheets/style.css 200 4.683 ms - 110
Warning: Unexpected block "content"  on line 3 of /srv/node/ase/views/error.jade. This block is never used. This warning will be an error in v2.0.0
GET /public/javascripts/gauge-main.js 404 12.587 ms - 154
GET /stylesheets/gauge-index.css 200 13.849 ms - 155
GET /stylesheets/gauge-simple.css 200 2.074 ms - 1025
GET /stylesheets/gauge-small.css 200 1.919 ms - 1014
GET /stylesheets/gauge-grayscale.css 200 1.857 ms - 1039
Warning: Unexpected block "content"  on line 3 of /srv/node/ase/views/error.jade. This block is never used. This warning will be an error in v2.0.0
GET /favicon.ico 404 10.821 ms - 154
Warning: Unexpected block "content"  on line 3 of /srv/node/ase/views/error.jade. This block is never used. This warning will be an error in v2.0.0
GET /favicon.ico 404 6.519 ms - 154
```

BTW, please ignore the other 404s for the favicon.

I think that since the '*.css' files are linked correctly using the relative path ('/stylesheets/...'), the same should be the case for the 'gauge-main.js' that is linked the same way ('/javascripts/gauge-main.js').

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is you're doing `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` because your css is being served correctly. So what you need to do is change your scripts' `src` values to start with `/javascripts/` instead of `/public/javascripts/`.